# Android- split the screen into two. And making left screen constant

Tags: android

In Android ,How to split the screen into two. And making left screen constant. I already got the split using fragments. I've to make left side view constant and have to navigate to the right side screen. for example left side contain 1.Phone 2. Music 3. navigation. (I am using default phone, music & navigation app ). I want to display android phone application in dedicated area. when I click on left side (Phone). The android phone application(Default phone) will appear on the right side for example.Now the problem is, The screen cover full area (I want Fixed left side). Why the activity screen is of full screen ? how to reduce the size of activity size? I am attaching sample code here.

**ListFragment**
    public class ListFrag extends ListFragment{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Phone", "Music", "Navigation"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_capt);
    if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
        frag.setText(getCapt(item));
    }
}

private String getCapt(String ship) {
    if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("phone")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, null);
        Log.i("", "*********************************");
        startActivity(i);
        //startActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone"));


    }
    if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("music")) {

        try {
            String pkgname = "com.sec.android.app.music";
            PackageManager pkgmanager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = pkgmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // music player not found
        }
    }
    if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("navigation")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.NavigationActivity");
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    return "";
}
```

}
Please help me

Comment: can u show image for this?

Comment: what happen when right side screen navigate to right

Comment: Given the relative lack of information, I'm assuming you mean something like the side bar used in the facebook app? If so, then you'd need to look at the (now) standard DrawerLayout. Heres a link to the android developer docs, detailing how to implement such things: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Failing that, we'll need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the DrawerLayout which comes along with Support package.

http://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/android-using-the-sliding-drawer-layout-from-support-package-v-4/